# Loading BioConductor library "GO.db" fails

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have a problem loading the BioConductor package "GO.db".
It fails with the error:

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'GO.db', details:
>   call: sqliteNewConnection(drv, ...)   error: RS-DBI driver: (could not
>   connect to dbname: unable to open database file ) Error: package or
>   namespace load failed for ‘GO.db’

I am working in Windows 8, using R 3.1.0 and Bioconductor 2.14 (latest versions).

Please help.

Full data:

> R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance" Copyright (C) 2014 The
>   R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
>   x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. You are
>   welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. Type 'license()'
>   or 'licence()' for distribution details.
>
> R is a collaborative project with many contributors. Type
>   'contributors()' for more information and 'citation()' on how to cite
>   R or R packages in publications.
>
> Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
>   'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help. Type 'q()' to
>   quit R.
>
> [Previously saved workspace restored]
>
> > source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R") Bioconductor version 2.14 (BiocInstaller 1.14.2), ?biocLite for help
> >     biocLite("GO.db") BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org Using Bioconductor version 2.14 (BiocInstaller 1.14.2), R version
> >       3.1.0. Installing package(s) 'GO.db' trying URL 'http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.14/data/annotation/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/GO.db_2.14.0.zip'
> >     Content type 'application/zip' length 27089981 bytes (25.8 Mb) opened
> >     URL downloaded 25.8 Mb
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>           C:\Users\קובי\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCGiNBg\downloaded_packages
>
> > library("GO.db") Loading required package: AnnotationDbi Loading required package: BiocGenerics Loading required package: parallel
>
> Attaching package: ‘BiocGenerics’
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:parallel’:
>
> ```
> clusterApply, clusterApplyLB, clusterCall, clusterEvalQ,
> clusterExport, clusterMap, parApply, parCapply, parLapply,
> parLapplyLB, parRapply, parSapply, parSapplyLB
> ```
>
> The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:
>
> ```
> xtabs
> ```
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
>
> ```
> anyDuplicated, append, as.data.frame, as.vector, cbind, colnames,
> do.call, duplicated, eval, evalq, Filter, Find, get, intersect,
> is.unsorted, lapply, Map, mapply, match, mget, order, paste, pmax,
> pmax.int, pmin, pmin.int, Position, rank, rbind, Reduce, rep.int,
> rownames, sapply, setdiff, sort, table, tapply, union, unique,
> unlist
> ```
>
> Loading required package: Biobase Welcome to Bioconductor
>
> ```
> Vignettes contain introductory material; view with
> 'browseVignettes()'. To cite Bioconductor, see
> 'citation("Biobase")', and for packages 'citation("pkgname")'.
> ```
>
> Loading required package: GenomeInfoDb Loading required package: DBI
>   Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'GO.db', details:
>   call: sqliteNewConnection(drv, ...)   error: RS-DBI driver: (could not
>   connect to dbname: unable to open database file ) Error: package or
>   namespace load failed for ‘GO.db’

Comment: does the command `BiocInstaller::biocValid()` suggest any packages that are out of date or too recent?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/39137110/134830

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. Try to reinstall R into another directory (another disc). It helped me.