# What does "The following object is masked from 'package:xxx'" mean?

Tags: r, package, include, r-faq

When I load a package, I get a message stating that:

```
"The following object is masked from 'package:xxx'
```

For example, if I load [`testthat`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/testthat) then [`assertive`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/assertive), I get the following:

```
library(testthat)
library(assertive)  
## Attaching package: ‘assertive’
## 
## The following objects are masked from ‘package:testthat’:
## 
##     has_names, is_false, is_less_than, is_null, is_true
```

What does this message mean, and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The message means that both the packages have functions with the same names. In this particular case, the `testthat` and `assertive` packages contain five functions with the same name.

#### When two functions have the same name, which one gets called?

R will look through the [`search`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/search) path to find functions, and will use the first one that it finds.

```
search()
 ##  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:assertive" "package:testthat" 
 ##  [4] "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
 ##  [7] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
 ## [10] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

In this case, since `assertive` was loaded after `testthat`, it appears earlier in the search path, so the functions in that package will be used.

```
is_true
## function (x, .xname = get_name_in_parent(x)) 
## {
##     x <- coerce_to(x, "logical", .xname)
##     call_and_name(function(x) {
##         ok <- x & !is.na(x)
##         set_cause(ok, ifelse(is.na(x), "missing", "false"))
##     }, x)
## }
<bytecode: 0x0000000004fc9f10>
<environment: namespace:assertive.base>
```

The functions in `testthat` are not accessible in the usual way; that is, they have been *masked*.

#### What if I want to use one of the masked functions?

You can explicitly provide a package name when you call a function, using the double colon operator, [`::`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/ns-dblcolon).  For example:

```
testthat::is_true
## function () 
## {
##     function(x) expect_true(x)
## }
## <environment: namespace:testthat>
```

#### How do I suppress the message?

If you know about the function name clash, and don't want to see it again, you can suppress the message by passing `warn.conflicts = FALSE` to [`library`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/library).

```
library(testthat)
library(assertive, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
# No output this time
```

Alternatively, suppress the message with [`suppressPackageStartupMessages`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/message):

```
library(testthat)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(assertive))
# Also no output
```

#### Impact of R's Startup Procedures on Function Masking

If you have altered some of R's startup configuration options (see `?Startup`) you may experience different function masking behavior than you might expect. The precise order that things happen as laid out in `?Startup` should solve most mysteries.

For example, the documentation there says:

> Note that when the site and user profile files are sourced only the
>   base package is loaded, so objects in other packages need to be
>   referred to by e.g. utils::dump.frames or after explicitly loading the
>   package concerned.

Which implies that when 3rd party packages are loaded via files like `.Rprofile` you may see functions from those packages masked by those in default packages like **stats**, rather than the reverse, if you loaded the 3rd party package after R's startup procedure is complete.

#### How do I list all the masked functions?

First, get a character vector of all the environments on the search path. For convenience, we'll name each element of this vector with its own value.

```
library(dplyr)
envs <- search() %>% setNames(., .)
```

For each environment, get the exported functions (and other variables).

```
fns <- lapply(envs, ls)
```

Turn this into a data frame, for easy use with dplyr.

```
fns_by_env <- data_frame(
  env = rep.int(names(fns), lengths(fns)),
  fn  = unlist(fns)
)
```

Find cases where the object appears more than once.

```
fns_by_env %>% 
  group_by(fn) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  filter(n > 1) %>% 
  inner_join(fns_by_env)
```

To test this, try loading some packages with known conflicts (e.g., [`Hmisc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc), [`AnnotationDbi`](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/AnnotationDbi.html)).

#### How do I prevent name conflict bugs?

The `conflicted` package throws an error with a helpful error message, whenever you try to use a variable with an ambiguous name.

```
library(conflicted)
library(Hmisc)
units
## Error: units found in 2 packages. You must indicate which one you want with ::
##  * Hmisc::units
##  * base::units
```

Comment: What if the library masks an object from the 'base' package, like `Hmisc::units`? I need to put it into the beginning of the search path to use it like this: `units(df$age)<-'y'`. Is there a method for that?

Comment: Is there a way to know all the maskings taking place at a certain time?

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski Use `base::units()`, just as you would with any other package.

Comment: @JohannesWentu I've updated my answer to explain how to do this.

Comment: [Package conflicted](https://github.com/r-lib/conflicted#conflicted) might also be useful for this situation.

Comment: @JohannesWentu You can call `conflict_scout()` from the package `conflicted` to report any conflicts in the current session.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I avoid it with `remove.packages("Package making this confusion")` and it works. In my case, I don't need the second package, so that is not a very good idea.