# R suppressMessages to avoid 'object masked' messages: pkgs dplyr and stats

Tags: r, package, dplyr, warnings, radix

I am using the R package dplyr for some (bash) command line scripting (using package `littler`) where I generate some tabular output (printing to stdout) that I want to pipe into another command.
When I in my script attach `dplyr` theres the warning that some bases object are masked.

```
Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

Is it `dplyr` or `base` that does not obey R's warnings. How can I turn this output off (since it ends up in the tabular output). These work not:

```
suppressMessages(library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F))


unloadNamespace(c("dplyr", "base"))
suppressMessages(library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F))
```

There is more general discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979917/how-to-unload-a-package-without-restarting-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137110/what-does-the-following-object-is-masked-from-packagexxx-mean)

Comment: `suppressMessages` and `suppressPackageStartupMessages` work for me, in an interactive session at least.

Comment: Nah I also tried the `suppressPackageStartupMessages` - same message.