# The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

Tags: r, ggplot2

When i try to execute ggplot2 and cowplot it threw me an error stating:

> Attaching package: ‘cowplot’
>
> ```
> The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:
>
>     ggsave
> ```

This is what i executed:

> ## library(ggplot2)
>
> ## library(cowplot)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "The following object is masked from 'package:xxx'" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137110/what-does-the-following-object-is-masked-from-packagexxx-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cowplot` package is masking `ggplot2::ggsave` to avoid confusion and throwing error of unrecognized object format when you try to to save `cowplot` object into e.g. pdf-file.
Please see example below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

# make a plot
p <- qplot(1:10, 1:10)
# draw into the top-right corner of a larger plot area
p1 <- ggdraw() + draw_plot(p, .6, .6, .4, .4)
ggsave("check.pdf", p1)
# Saving 7.17 x 5.6 in image
# everything is OK

ggplot2::ggsave("check1,pdf", p1)
# Error: Unknown graphics device ''
```

In case facing problems using `ggsave` by default called of `cowplot` package you can call it as `ggplot2::ggsave`. For details please see [What does "The following object is masked from 'package:xxx'" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137110/what-does-the-following-object-is-masked-from-packagexxx-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1)  in accordance to PoGibas's comment.